# Sort a alphanumeric column in pandas and replace it with original column of the dataset

Tags: pandas

My input is

```
Name        Date                  ID
Ram    2017-04-01 00:00:00      ABCD12A
Rahul  2017-04-11 20:00:00      ABCD12B
Vivek  2017-04-03 06:00:00      ABCD11C
```

Expected Output:

```
Name        Date                  ID
Vivek  2017-04-03 06:00:00      ABCD11C
Ram    2017-04-01 00:00:00      ABCD12A
Rahul  2017-04-11 20:00:00      ABCD12B
```

Comment: Do you want `df = df.sort_values('ID')` ? If yes, it is dupe :(

Comment: No. It is not as the other question. Here 'ABCD' is to be taken as string and 11 as integer and again C or B or A as string

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Can you please unmark it as duplicate, so that other's can answer

Comment: Sorry, can you add more data for better explanation? Why `df = df.sort_values('ID')` does not work? Or is necessary cut `ID` column for 3 separately columns and sort by them? Or need `natsorting` ?

Comment: I can and I want reopen it, but I think your question need more information. Can you add it?